# Firebase Cloud Function deploy functions error: lint: eslint

Tags: java, node.js, firebase, npm

I have followed a tutorial to implement an observe follower notification.

```
exports.observeFollowing = functions.database.ref('/following/{uid}/{followingId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
var uid = context.params.uid;
var followingId = context.params.followingId;
console.log('User: ' + uid + ' is following: ' + followingId);
return admin.database().ref('/users/' + followingId).once('value', snapshot => {
  var userWeAreFollowing = snapshot.val();
  return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {
    var userDoingTheFollowing = snapshot.val();
    var payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "You now have a new follower",
        body: userDoingTheFollowing.username + "is now following you",
        sound: 'default'
      }
    }
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userWeAreFollowing.fcmToken, payload)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        return response;
      }).catch(function(error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });
  })
})
```

})

However, when I tried to run firebase deploy --only functions:observeFollowing I receive the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I had tried to search answers from Stackoverflow but none of the answers seen to work.

Comment: Did you try to update the local version of firebase-functions and firebase-admin ?

Comment: You're not actually showing the eslint error message here.  Examine the output of the Firebase CLI more carefully.  Be sure to consider the entire output.